# Angular Authguard displays a blank page

Tags: angular, auth-guard

I'm using AuthGuard for some of my routes:

```
  {
    path: "dashboard",
    component: DashboardComponent,
    pathMatch: "full",
    canActivate: [RoleGuardService],
    data: {
      expectedRole: Role.ROLE_ADMIN,
    },
  },
```

And my roleguard.service

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleGuardService implements CanActivate {
  constructor(public auth: AuthService, public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): boolean {
    const expectedRole = route.data.expectedRole;
    if (!this.auth.hasRole(expectedRole)) {
      this.router.navigate(["login"], {
        queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url },
      });
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

If I log into the application and then use the UI to navigate to the dashboard everything works as expected. If I enter the URL in the browser `localhost:4200/dashboard` I get a blank page.

What am I missing?

Edit: typo

Edit: this is my current authService:

```
  public hasRole(r: string): boolean {
    let hasRole = false;
    this.getCurrentRoles().forEach((role) => {
      if (role.authority === r) {
        hasRole = true;
      }
    });
    return hasRole;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of directly hitting the URL your expectedRole will be always false and since you have not provided any router.navigate for false condition therefore you get the blank page.

You can subscribe to the service which gives the correct value of expectedRole and than define your if statement conditions accordingly. This would work in all cases.

For Example:

Service:

```
  private isAdmin = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.checkForAdmin());
  isUserAdmin = this.isAdmin.asObservable();

  checkForAdmin():boolean
  {
    const userName = localStorage.getItem("userName");

    if(userName == "Admin") //Replace with your expectedRole check
    {
      return true
    }
    return false;

  }
```

Inside Guard:

```
this.adminService.iAdmin.subscribe(result=>this.userAdmin=result)
        if (this.userAdmin) {
    
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          console.log('Could not authenticate Admin');
       
       // to the desired or default page

          this.router.navigate(['dashboard'],{queryParams:{'redirectURL':state.url}});
          //return false;
        }
```

Comment: alright yes that makes sense. Could you please provide a short example of what the adminService would look like? I updated my post and added my current authService

Comment: You can store the user role in local storage or global variable after user is logs in and used the stored value to perform you ExpectedRole check